# How to override fields in groovy

Tags: groovy

```
class A {
    def p = 18
    def out() {
        println(p)
    }
}
class B extends A {
    def p = 21
}

new B().out()
```

I have the snippet as above. The output is `****`.. Guess what?

My question is - how can I achieve results as it would be in java?

*ps: groovy console works fine for those who wants execute sample above: groovyconsole.appspot.com*

***UPD* :**
transforming property to method solves issue. any other options?

Comment: When I try this in Java, then the output is 18, not 21. So Groovy behaves just like Java in that regard

Comment: @blackdrag you're right. shame on me. I forgot java:(

Comment: Don't worry, when I implemented that for Groovy I was really wondering if something like this should be even allowed in Java. I can understand it for private fields, but with other accessibilities too? Well... I kept it for now  in Groovy too ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about overriding the value of `p` in an initializer block?

```
class B extends A {
    { p = 21 }
}
```